# Prove that the Countable Intersection is not Empty

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $ [a_1,b_1] \supset [a_2,b_2] \supset [a_3,b_3] \supset ... $ then $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n] $ is not empty.

I started with going by contradiction and assume the intersection is empty. Then I continued on saying that then there exists some $ [a_i,b_i] $ such that its intersection is empty amongst every other closed interval. Was my accusation correct? I feel like I am missing something or I made an incorrect accusation. Please no answer to the question. Just a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Try $\sup a_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not go with a contradiction here.

Instead, consider the set of left endpoints $A = \{a_n\}$ and the set of right endpoints $B = \{b_n\}$. Then, if you let $x = $ Sup($A$) you can show that $a_n \leqslant x \leqslant b_n$. From that you know the intersection is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have $a_n\le a_{n+1}\le b_{n+1}\le b_n$ for all $n$. So, are the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ convergent? If so, what can you say about their limits?